# Logarithmic code in R programming with 3 variables

Tags: r, logarithm

I have written a small program to develop logarithmic code and I have taken 3 variables, `x`, `y` and `p`, where `x` is base, `y` is log value and `p` is default value (power of '`x`'). Now I am not getting error when I executed it but it didn't display any answer on terminal. It will be handy when someone provide solution to it.

```
algo1 <- function(x, y) {
  p <- 1
if (x ^ p == y) {
  print(p)
} else {
  p <- p + 1
}

algo1(3, 81)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues I can see here.

1. Assigning `p` inside the function, while it seems the function has to be recursive.
2. OR, considering for some reason you want to increment `p` within the `else` condition and still not do anything with the incremented value, not returning anything here.

If I may, I would change the function to something like:

```
algo1 <- function(x,y,p = 1) {
  if (x ^ p == y) {
    print(p)
  } else {
    p = p + 1
    algo1(x,y,p)
  }
}
```

which returns the value of `p` for which `x^p ==y`

```
> algo1(3,81)
[1] 4
```

OR, you can also use:

```
round(y ^ (1.0/x))
```

p.s. maybe include a check and exit conditions for `x^p > y`?

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem, why #algo1(x,y,p) should be added? and how can i be in touch with you as a new person to R - programming.

Comment: if i pass values algo1(5,0.0016) it shows infinite solution

Comment: Initialising `p` is not specific to R language, please read [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html) and [here for R examples](https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/recursion).
It goes to infinite loops as we initialise `p = 1` and go up, and does not include a termination condition for such cases. 
What output do you expect for such an input?

Answer (score 1):

First, there's a problem with your code where you don't close the function (i.e. you're missing the final `}`) and you're mixing `<-` and `=` assignments (stick with one):

```
algo1 <- function(x, y) {
  p <- 1
  if (x ^ p == y) {
    print(p)
  } else {
    p <- p + 1
  }
}
```

After solving this, you're not getting a returned value because you're not `return()`ing anything. To return, just place the variable in the code:

```
algo1 <- function(x, y) {
  p <- 1
  if (x ^ p == y) {
    p
  } else {
    p <- p + 1
    p
  }
}
```

The function now returns:

```
algo1(3, 81)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Would this not return the value `2` for all non-equal values of `x` and `y`? 
Agreed, OP has not mentioned clearly what he wants, still...

Comment: Possibly, I didn't look at the logic, just why it wasn't returning.

Comment: Thanks for responding and providing  solution to my question even though i wasn't clear with my question. Hope next time i will clearly mention it